# XSLT doen't work with opera

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, firefox, xslt, opera

I have a XML file connected to a XSL file. When I open the XML Firefox and IE can load it and display it without problems but Opera 22.0 just show me an empty page.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="bibliography.xsl"?>
<bibliography xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="bibliography.xsd">
<phdthesis>
    <name>
        Abadie:92
  </name>
    <author>
         B. Abadie
  </author>
    <title>
         On the K-theory of non-commutative Heisenberg manifolds
  </title>
    <school>
         Univ. of California at Berkeley
  </school>
    <year>
         1992
  </year>
</phdthesis>
<inproceedings>
    <name>
        Abadie:94
  </name>
    <author>
         B. Abadie
  </author>
    <title>
         ''Vector bundles'' over quantum Heisenberg manifolds
  </title>
    <booktitle>
         Algebraic Methods in Operator Theory
  </booktitle>
    <year>
         1994
  </year>
    <editor>
         R. Curto and P. E. T. J&#248;rgensen
  </editor>
    <publisher>
         Birkh&#228;user, Boston - Basel - Berlin
  </publisher>
    <note>
         307-315
  </note>
</inproceedings>
...
a lot of more elements
...
</bibliography>
```

And my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Bibliographie</title>
            <style type="text/css">
            .entry {
                font-family: Georgia
            }
            .entry italic {
                font-style: italic
            }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/bibliography/*">
    <p>
        <div class="entry{@type}">
    [<xsl:number count="*"/>]
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Am I missing something in these files?

Comment: Are you loading the XML document over HTTP or from the file system? Have you checked the error console whether it shows some security problem or other indication what could be the problem?

Comment: The console says: `Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///D:/Dropbox/path/bibliography.xsl from frame with URL file:///D:/Dropbox/path/bibliography-with-xsd.xml. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

Comment: Sounds like your security settings aren't allowing XSLT to be executed from the local file system. No idea how to change this.

Comment: So you are trying to load the file from the file system. I think recent versions of Opera are based on Google Chrome and that doesn't allow either to load XML from the file system and have XSLT applied, unless you start Chrome with lowered security settings. I don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 'fixed' it with using opera 12. As the others said, operas security settings in newer versions doesn't allow opening a XML and XSL from the same local file system.